JOIN DirectMessage table with User table for a LIKE query on the SENDER_ID -> FIRST_NAME
I have a DirectMessage table which looks like this:

And a User table which has columns like:
ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | etc...

I currently have a query that will return all of the latest messages, distinct by ultimate_parent_id. Also I have a LIKE query to be able to search for text within the TITLE of each DirectMessage.
What I would like to add is another search query clause, but in this case I would have to JOIN on the Users table and do a LIKE on the FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME. I'm not sure where to go about it.
This is the query that is working for returning the list of messages searching by title:
SELECT 
    outerDM.* 
FROM 
    direct_message outerDM 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         ultimate_parent_id, MAX(sent_at) AS last_sent 
     FROM 
         direct_message 
     WHERE 
         recipient_id = :recipientId 
         AND (UPPER(title) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :searchQuery, '%')))
     GROUP BY 
         ultimate_parent_id) innerDM ON outerDM.ultimate_parent_id = innerDM.ultimate_parent_id 
                                     AND outerDM.sent_at = innerDM.last_sent 
ORDER BY 
    sent_at DESC

How can I add a LIKE search on the first_name or last_name of the sender (stored as sender_id in the DirectMessage table)?
In this case - return the DirectMessage if the SENDER_ID -> FIRST_NAME matches the text query. So joining DirectMessage and Users.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. That image of data is totally useless. It can't be easily read, it can't be copied and pasted to use to create a table to use when writing an answer, and it's not available to mobile users or people behind a corporate proxy.

LIKE is a bit vague here. What exactly do you mean by LIKE - the first letters match, any letters match, two letters match ... its not always so easy to nail down such "fuzzy matching" when you actually start to try doing it.
